# counting methodolegy in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server-2008

Good day everyone…
I have a database that has the following:
Division table that linked to Employee table.
Group table, i.e. courses categories, that linked to Courses table.
and these table linked together thru Curses_Employee table .
so far I managed to come up with a query that give me the number of users who toke certain course in each group/category like the following output table:
groupName | DivisionName| courseName|Total Number of Participants

and here is my query for the above scheme:

```
SELECT     dbo.groups.GroupName, dbo.Divisions.DivisionName, dbo.courses.CourseName, COUNT(dbo.employee_courses.courseId) AS [Total Number of Participants]
FROM         dbo.employee AS employee_1 INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Divisions ON employee_1.DivisionCode = dbo.Divisions.SapCode INNER JOIN
                      dbo.employee_courses ON employee_1.Username = dbo.employee_courses.employeeId INNER JOIN
                      dbo.courses ON dbo.employee_courses.courseId = dbo.courses.CourseID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.groups ON dbo.courses.GroupID = dbo.groups.ID
WHERE     (dbo.courses.GroupID = 2)
GROUP BY dbo.courses.CourseID, dbo.courses.CourseName, dbo.Divisions.DivisionName, dbo.groups.GroupName
```

now I want to add two columns the total number of employee in each division as well as the % like the following table:
groupName | DivisionName| courseName|Total Number of Participants |Total Number of Employee |%

I tried this query but it give me an error:

```
SELECT     dbo.groups.GroupName, dbo.Divisions.DivisionName, dbo.courses.CourseName, COUNT(dbo.employee_courses.courseId) AS [Total Number of Participants],
                          (SELECT     COUNT(Name) AS Expr1
                            FROM          dbo.employee
                            WHERE      (DivisionCode = employee_1.DivisionCode)
                            GROUP BY DivisionCode) AS [Total Number of Employee]
FROM         dbo.employee AS employee_1 INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Divisions ON employee_1.DivisionCode = dbo.Divisions.SapCode INNER JOIN
                      dbo.employee_courses ON employee_1.Username = dbo.employee_courses.employeeId INNER JOIN
                      dbo.courses ON dbo.employee_courses.courseId = dbo.courses.CourseID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.groups ON dbo.courses.GroupID = dbo.groups.ID
WHERE     (dbo.courses.GroupID = 2)
GROUP BY dbo.courses.CourseID, dbo.courses.CourseName, dbo.Divisions.DivisionName, dbo.groups.GroupName
```

the error message:

> column 'dbo.employee.DivisionCode' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either as aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Comment: "but it give me an error" - crystall balls out....

Comment: the error message:
column 'dbo.employee.DivisionCode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either as aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Kemoid, you might consider editing the question to include the error. Placing it in a comment can result in it being hidden to the people who are trying to help you.